# What happened after Rita stopped resetting?

Tags: plot-explanation, edge-of-tomorrow

Rita was in the time loop at 1st. She kept dying and dying until she got hurt and they pumped someone else's blood into her. My question is what happened the next day after she woke up from not having to reset?

What happened to the war up until Cage came along? Since she couldn't reset anymore did that mean the war stopped? Couldn't have if Cage got sent into it

Comment: I don't understand why the war would stop.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion seems to stem from misunderstanding what is looping and resetting.

The war is not what is being reset - it is the personal timelines of Rita and then Cage. Their looping is because they initially die after being contaminated with some of the aliens' blood and they are grafted the looping ability.

The aliens must have either evolved or developed the ability to loop their own timelines on death so that they can adapt and learn to overcome whatever killed them initially. So, there are actually multiple timelines being reset all over the place as aliens die and reset.

All in all - it's probably not a good idea to get much further into the physical and metaphysical ramifications, because it's apt to give even Doctor Who a nasty headache...

Comment: Ok last question... when Rita lost her power what was taking place up until Cage came? What was she doing? Did the Omega decide to pause the fight until someone else came along?

Comment: The war continued - the enemy kept resetting their own timelines and won ever more victories against the humans.

Comment: OP thought the war is what being reseted? Now the question makes some sense.

Comment: @DreonJediRacing Think of it like five people watching a VHS tape (ah the good old days), and all 5 of them are holding a remote that can rewind the tape.

Answer (score 2):

You kind of answered your own question: the war didn't stop. It couldn't have, since it was still happening when Cage got sent to it.

The movie doesn't tell us clearly what happened between Rita's heroics and Cage's loop. But we can assume that Rita was very heroic because of getting to relive the same battles over and over until she got them "right". Then, she lost her ability to reset, so she lost her edge - she was in situations she'd never experience before.  However, she was already a brave figurehead for the war effort by that point.

The war continued, Cage got enlisted, and he got into his own reset loop. He became the new hero.

Comment: It didnt stop? So what kept resetting it if she couldnt?

Comment: If no one died then the omega wouldn't have needed to reset

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "what kept resetting it", but I'll tell you what I think happened. I'll even make up some dates.  January 1, Rita gets the ability to reset, and every time she dies (on January 1, or January 2, or January 3), everything gets reset to January 1. She then loses her ability, maybe on January 2 or 3 or 4. The war keeps going on January 5, 6, 7, 8.... On January 9, Cage gets the ability to reset. When he dies on January 9, time resets. January 10 he dies, it resets to January 9. So the new "loop" goes back to January 9.